# Efficient Method in MATLAB for Producing a Numerical Solution to an Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

I am attempting to write a MATLAB program that allows me to give it a differential equation and then ultimately produce a numerical solution.

In particular, I am looking to solve this equation:
[image]

The steps involved to create such a program would be, as I see it:

1st: Discretizing the domain of the ODE into n-intervals of equivalent length
2nd: Replace the differential operators write finite difference operators.
3rd: Somehow get MATLAB to construct a system of linear equations that approximates the ODE
4th: Solve the system of linear algebraic equations with MATLAB
5th: Plot the results.

And, on that conceptual level, that all makes sense to me. Attempting to carry out the steps using code is what is proving difficult.

Thus far, I have the program split into two parts. The first one is my attempt at graphing the function, while the second part attempts to perform the integration.

First Part:

```html
function [y] = ODEs (n,a, b)
x= 0:(1/n):1;
A= zeros(n+1,n+1);
A(1,1)= -2;
A(1,2)= 1;
A(n+1, n+1)= -2;
A(n+1, n)=1;
for i= 2:n;
    A(i,i)=-2;
    A(i,i-1)=1;
    A(i,i-1)=1;
end

for i=1:n+1;
    b(i,1)=(x(1,i)).* (1/n);
end

y=inv(A)*b;

plot (x,y)
hold all
plot (x,(x(:).^3./6) +(b-a-(1/6)).*x(:) +a)
```

Second Part:

```html
clear all;
 
clc;
 
prompt='How many times do you want to integrate the function y=x: ';
 
 
 
y = input(prompt);
 
 
syms ('x');
 
i = 1;
 
j = 1;
 
b = 1;
 
den_num = 1;
 
 
 
while i <= y
    
   
    while j <= y 
        den_num = j*den_num;
        j = j+1;
    end
   b = x.^y /den_num;
   
    i = i+1;
end
pretty(b)
```

At this point, both parts are riddled with errors (the 2nd part doesn't even provide a graph like I would like), but hopefully what I'm attempting to do is clear. I'm not looking for a solution to all my problems to be handed to me: I know that would prove immense. However, it would be nice to know if I'm heading in the right direction? Or is there a more efficient way of going about things that I'm missing? Hopefully this all makes some sense.

Comment: Are you aware that MATLAB already has existing ODE solvers e.g. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html ?

Comment: @CerebralCortexan: *I'd like to know how to do it myself* – Then start reading about how existing methods work, e.g., [Runge–Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). Solving ODEs is a science of its own. By trying it yourself, you will at best reinvent the wheel. Most likely, however, you will just produce garbage.

Comment: see also [Fluxions for Fun and Profit: Euler, Trapezoidal, Verlet, or Runge-Kutta?](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/474.php)